# How to output raw HTML code inside an Editable DIV

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying to output raw HTML inside an editable DIV, but the `<div>` get commented out.

This is what I am trying to output :

```
var myRawInnerHTMLVal = async (revVarArgs) => {
    let myWidgetView = '<div class="flexContainerClass">HELLO WORLD</div>';

    return myWidgetView;
};

module.exports.myRawInnerHTMLVal = myRawInnerHTMLVal;
```

this is what I get instead (*Please NOTE* **`HELLO WORLD`** *is not wrapped inside a div*) :

```
var myRawInnerHTMLVal = async (revVarArgs) => {
    let myWidgetView = 'HELLO WORLD';

    return myWidgetView;
};

module.exports.myRawInnerHTMLVal = myRawInnerHTMLVal;
```

**THE CALL**

```
document.getElementById(myEditableDIVInputArea_Id).innerHTML = `
    var myRawInnerHTMLVal = async (revVarArgs) => {
        let myWidgetView = '<div class="flexContainerClass">HELLO WORLD</div>';

        return myWidgetView;
    };

    module.exports.myRawInnerHTMLVal = myRawInnerHTMLVal;
`;
```

How can I get the raw HTML output?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: so, what you are trying is to show some code in div right? why don't you show it as text ? 
`document.getElementById(myEditableDIVInputArea_Id).textContent = your code`. better if the `myEditableDIVInputArea_Id` is a `code` tag instead of `div` so you may get the intendations

Comment: The `innerHtml` will do the work of removing the `<div>` tags. You should instead use `textContent` like said in the above comment.

Answer (score 0):

Call value property instead of innerHTML:

```
document.getElementById(myEditableDIVInputArea_Id).value = myRawInnerHTMLVal;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're not calling the function and you're not awaiting it (it's async), in this case you don't need it to be async.

```js
var myRawInnerHTMLVal = (revVarArgs) => {
    let myWidgetView = '<div class="flexContainerClass">HELLO WORLD</div>';

    return myWidgetView;
};

module.exports.myRawInnerHTMLVal = myRawInnerHTMLVal;
```

```js
document.getElementById(myEditableDIVInputArea_Id).innerHTML = myRawInnerHTMLVal(args);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I am trying to print out the whole `var myRawInnerHTMLVal = (revVarArgs) => {
    let myWidgetView = '<div class="flexContainerClass">HELLO WORLD</div>';

    return myWidgetView;
};

module.exports.myRawInnerHTMLVal = myRawInnerHTMLVal;`

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but if you want to append the HTML instead of replacing it then you could use the shorthand `+=` operator (at the end it's just concatenating a string to another), like `document.getElementById(myEditableDIVInputArea_Id).innerHTML += myRawInnerHTMLVal(args);`